# Store with multiple reducers from different components. React / Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a store that needs to connect to different components. I created 3 different slices and wanted to make a dependency with the store.
When I hook all of three reducers :

```
export const store = configureStore({
reducer : {
  home : homeSlice,
  about : aboutSlice,
  review : reviewSlice,
},
});
```

I get the next error :

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Answer (score 1):

As in react, documentation hooks can be called only inside of a functional component. The code you provide to merge reducers is correct. You need to use `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks inside the component functions to retrieve the value or dispatch an action respectively. What is the main issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

You are somehow using store incorrectly.

The Store needs to be passed to the Provider (which wraps all the components inside app.js).

```
import {store} from 'your_path'

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MyApplication />
  </Provider>
)
```

After that, you can already use Redux inside components.
To change states, use the useDispatch() hook,
and to get the state useSelector().
Here is a link to documentation about hooks in React-Redux https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks